# Android: Adjust the buttons above soft keyboard on clicking edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, window-soft-input-mode

I am trying to adjust the softkeyboard right below the image buttons, but it covers the image buttons which does not makes it clickable . I want the buttons to be right above the softkeyboard when the user clicks on the edittext. I have tried using the `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, but it does not seem to work.

Below is my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/addnote"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/addnote_title"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Title">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/addnote_title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/addnote_descp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Notes">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/addnote_descp_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:lines="10"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/check_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bold_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/format_bold"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the AndroidManifest.xml file i have

```
<activity
    android:name=".AddNote"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will show buttons above the keyboard. When we do want to display any view above the keyboard that view should be aligned bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/addnote"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/addnote_title"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="Title">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/addnote_title_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/addnote_descp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="Notes">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/addnote_descp_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:lines="10"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/check_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bold_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```